# linux after restore + GRUB error

Tags: linux, grub, restore

[image]

I restored Linux machine , and when the Linux machine startup I get the following errors

```
  GNU GRUB version 0.97

  GRUB>
```

Please advice how we can fix that? In order to startup my linux machine?

[image: linux after restore]

Comment: This info is not much help. You're only showing the grub screen, not the error. It will be hard to obtain help only providing this info. Also, people here can be obnoxious because your attaching Windows XP screenshots in the Internet Explorer.

Comment: see the picture , how I can fix this grub in order to start the linux , whats the options???

Comment: That's my point: What need to be fixed? There is no error in this screen. There isn't even a clue about the error. If you need to start from this CLI the hard drive address is needed (hd0, hd1) as well as the partition were the linux kernel image is inside the hard drive, maybe reading this will help: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands.html

Comment: could you explain how to boot from the hard drive ? which grub command I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Before delving into the details of Grub, I suggest using your Linux live disk (or USB) to re-install Grub and see if that helps. Alternatively, get Grub4DOS and try installing that.

Since you're using Grub 0.97 the Grub 2 manual won't be so helpful, since there are quite a few differences between old Grub and new Grub. Here's the manual for [Grub 0.97](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/).

Section [4.2.2 GNU/Linux](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/GNU_002fLinux.html#GNU_002fLinux) gives a brief explanation of how to boot Linux from the Grub commandline. But you will need to know the exact name & location of the relevant files to do so.

Also take a look at section `13.3.13 geometry`, and you may find `13.3.3 cat` helpful, too.

FWIW, Grub4DOS is quite similar to old Grub, but with several improvements.